# Join 2 tables (one-to-many) and get newest entry in second table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Assuming I have two tables, "users" and "audit", and the audit table is populated by a trigger each time the user's status changes. I'm trying to do a select from both tables, and get the user entry (unique) with the associated latest audit entry. Say the tables have the following fields:

users:

- id
- username
- email
- status

audit:

- id (just an arbitrary autoincrement)
- user_id (fk)
- new_status
- created_at (date/time when this happened)

**Thus, for each user entry, there's multiple audit entries.**

So, eventually I need the result to be say (where the italic part is the results from audit, and the non-italic is the user part of the row in the mysql result-set):
**1**, john, john@gmail.com, 10, *5, **1**, 10, 2012-08-10-10:15:59*
etc

Now, the only way I can see is to do compounded selects, where I do something like:
SELECT U.*, (SELECT * FROM audit A2 where A2.id = max(A.id)) FROM users U left join audit A on (U.id = A.user_id);

Problem is, if you're having thousands or perhaps hundreds of thousands of results in user, you'll be doing n+1 queries internally in the DB - which is really inefficient.

Any ideas on how to write this as one SQL statement without using compounded SELECTS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming there is always a corresponding audit entry, and have thus used INNER JOIN. Also assuming there are not two audit entries with the same `created_at` date for the same user.

```
select u.id, u.username, u.email, u.status, 
    a.id, a.new_status, a.created_at
from users u
inner join (
    select user_id, max(created_at) as MaxCreated
    from audit
    group by user_id
) am on u.id = am.user_id
inner join audit a on am.user_id = a.user_id and am.MaxCreated = a.created_at
```

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't that cause 1000+1 internal SELECT statements on the server if there is for instance 1000 users? It will do the 1st select for all the users, then a select for each user to get the result. What I'm trying to achieve is a select statement that avoids that. (That's, off course, if it is possible hehe)

Comment: @Sarel No, the inner select is a derived table, i.e., it will run once. Notice that it is not a correlated subquery - you can run the subquery on its own, it does not use data from the other tables. That derived table then gets joined back against `users` and `audit`.

Comment: Ah wow yeah, great! Thanks man... this is working like a charm in our production server :) *high fives*

Comment: This was very very helpful. Based on my now-working code I *think* line 8 should read 

`) AS am on u.id = am.user_id`

Is the 'AS' not necessary?

Comment: @DavidRhoden The `AS` is optional.